# Matplotlib: Make subplot fill axes tick/labels space

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I'm creating a multi-panel figure, and I have an image I show using `matplotlib.image.imshow` in one of the panels. I want to maximize space utilization, so this image can be seen in higher detail.

I cannot find documentation to expand this image into the whitespace occupied by axes ticks and labels in other subplots. Have tried the various layout options ([`TightLayout`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html), [`GridSpec`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html) or [`ConstrainedLayout`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html)).

Here is an example image from the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/specialty_plots/mri_with_eeg.html#sphx-glr-gallery-specialty-plots-mri-with-eeg-py). The desired version of this figure would be with the MRI image expanded to touch the bottom horizontal of the "Intensity (a.u.)" label. The aspect ratio of the MRI image should be maintained.

Any wisdom?

[image: matplotlib MRI example]

Comment: My exact figure has a grid layout of (2,3), where the (0,0) = image 1, (1,0) = Image 2, (0:2,1) = Graph1, (0:2,2) = Graph2.

Comment: You can use `imshow(..., aspect='auto')` but beware that your image will be stretched to fill the space.

Comment: You can get the position of the xlabel and set the bottom of the image axes to that position manually.